# Are backups overwritten?

Tags: backup

I understand that a full backup means, "copy everything", whereas an incremental backup means, "copy only changes files". Also, full backup takes a lot of space but incremental backup does not.

Generally, why don't we always take the incremental backup and commit it to the full back at the same time and delete the old backup? If we do so, we would always have the latest files (in full backup mode).

When we take a full backup, is the previous backup overwritten? If not, then why?

Comment: Short answer: Corrupted backups together with the convenience of incrementals.

Answer (score 1):

If your system fails during a backup, the whole backup may be corrupted. And if someone needs to get back a file they deleted two weeks ago, the backup won’t have it if you’re deleting all the old ones. Backup isn’t just about preserving the most recent state of the data, it’s also about being able to go back in time.